# I want to use XQuery For Xml processing in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery, javax.xml

I want to use `XQuery` for fetching data from Xml in java, but I am not getting which Jar I need to add for this. I searched in google lot but haven't got any useful example. For example I got following link:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqj.htm

Then I am not getting jar file mentioned here. Anyone know how to start using XQuery in Java with a simple example will be very helpful. After lot of search I have got this link which is saying `Xqjapi.jar` comes with oracle database.

https://technology.amis.nl/2011/07/30/running-xquery-from-java-applications-using-the-xqj-api-and-the-oracle-xdk-implementation/

Is there any open source api I can use in Java for using `XQuery`?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/index-100632.html

Comment: thanks for answering,But As far I have read,If i need to use oracle library,oracle database should be there.here I want to create a simple java class and there i want to fetch a element of xml using xquery.

Comment: @AnanthaSharma plz see the comment above

Comment: @AnanthaSharma please see the below link- https://technology.amis.nl/2011/07/30/running-xquery-from-java-applications-using-the-xqj-api-and-the-oracle-xdk-implementation/

Comment: well even I have no good news as such, just read in this link here, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2556726, you need to install database for related jars, but still looking, will update here if found something useful. Also can you change one line in your question, `Anyone know how to start using jquery in java with a simple example will be very helpfull.` ., I guess it should be `XQuery` and not `jquery`.

Comment: @ShrikantHavale thanks for your comment.I will update it sure.

Comment: I think it cud be used also-http://www.tutorialspoint.com/xquery/xquery_environment.htm

Answer (score 6):

Well, there is another approach to get the required `JARS`, you need not install oracle database for that. I found the solution in this link,

http://orafmwsoa.blogspot.co.at/2014/06/running-xquery-from-java-applications.html

But you need not go through the entire link, what important point to note is, all necessary `JARS` are available from Oracle XQuery for Hadoop implementation.

And here is the link,

[Oracle XQuery for Hadoop 2.4.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/bdc/big-data-connectors/downloads/index.html)

Just download `Oracle XQuery for Hadoop 4.1.0` and extract and create a normal Java Project with the libraries in path.

I tried this example from your link, and it works

```
import javax.xml.xquery.XQConnection;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQException;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQPreparedExpression;
import javax.xml.xquery.XQSequence;
import oracle.xml.xquery.OXQDataSource;


public class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) throws XQException {
    OXQDataSource ds = new OXQDataSource();
    XQConnection con = ds.getConnection();
    String query = "<hello-world>{1 + 1}</hello-world>";
    XQPreparedExpression expr = con.prepareExpression(query); 
    XQSequence result = expr.executeQuery();
    System.out.println(result.getSequenceAsString(null));
    
    result.close();
    expr.close();
    con.close();
}

}
```

With following `JARS` in path,

> apache-xmlbeans
>
> orai18n-mapping
>
> oxquery
>
> xmlparserv2_sans_jaxp_services
>
> xqjapi

Also another suggestion,

1. I installed Oracle Express Edition 11.2 `OracleXE112_Win64` and it didn't had the required `JARS`, XE may be has limited functionality, so try installing different one.
2. Also this link here [Embedding XQuery in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136921/embedding-xquery-in-java) suggests usage of SAXON XSLT & XQuery processor. [SAXON](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is in filestore, then you need a filestore-based XQuery processor such as Saxon.

Comment: To expand on this answer - XQJ is just an API, and it is one of several different APIs that you could use for processing XQuery from Java. If you have a few documents on a filesystem then you can use a file based processor such as Saxon. If you use Saxon. I would suggest using its S9API as opposed to XQJ though as it is a nicer fit. If you have many XML files then you might want to consider a Native XML Database, in which instance as you are using Java I would suggest eXist or BaseX; The eXist O'Reilly book has a Java API chapter.